# Does one hardhat package export wallets addresses and private keys?

Tags: javascript, hardhat

Hardhat contains 20 wallets that can be used by developers. When starting docker, this gets logged:

```
Accounts
========

WARNING: These accounts, and their private keys, are publicly known.
Any funds sent to them on Mainnet or any other live network WILL BE LOST.

Account #0: 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80

Account #1: 0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8 (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0x59c6995e998f97a5a0044966f0945389dc9e86dae88c7a8412f4603b6b78690d

Account #2: 0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0x5de4111afa1a4b94908f83103eb1f1706367c2e68ca870fc3fb9a804cdab365a
...
```

I would like to know wether they are exported by on of these packages

`@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers`
`@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan`
`@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle`

or by any other package that i could use, to avoid having them to be declared manually.

I'm looking for something like

```
import { wallets } from "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers";

console.log(wallets[0].adress, wallets[0].privateKey)
// 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266, 0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80
```

I read through a lot of pages of the documentation and searched the packages manually but haven't found anything.